# Spring Cloud and AWS Lambda: Issue with MAIN_CLASS not being found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-cloud

In the past I have created AWS Lambdas using Spring Cloud Function and everything worked fine. I believe I used Spring Boot 3.0.0 and used Java 11. Now I am currently using Spring 3.1.6 and Java 17 to create a sample function and I cannot seem to get it to work like before. Below, I will show what my Pom file looks like as well. I even added a MANIFEST.MF in the correct file structure, and I am still not getting the function to be called. Since the last time I created the working function, it has only been roughly 8 months. Has there been any significant changes In how to invoke the function?

AWS Handler portion (How you used to invoke the function within AWS)
org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker::handleRequest

File Structure

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.function.Function;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String,String> capitalize(){return String::toUpperCase;}

}
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did the following to solve the issue. AWS tries to run the 'java -jar  ' command and cannot find any manifest data in your compressed JAR. Then it tries to read it from the environment variables '**MAIN_CLASS**' and '**START_CLASS**'. Of course, you can put them into your environment variable, but the spoiler is: it does not work. After that, you encounter another error because your serverless functions cannot be cataloged.

The real problem is your shaded JAR, which is generated without the manifest and required dependencies. At this point, check the following in your pom.xml:

1. ensure that the **parent** is defined as following (regardless of the version). It contains libraries that you need in your application context and afterwards in your shaded jar.

   ```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
   </parent>
   ```
2. add the start class in your properties:

   ```
   <properties>
       ...
       <start-class>com.example.YourMainClass</start-class>
       ...
   <properties>
   ```
3. Define your shaded jar plugin correctly! In following I copied the entire build tag of my pom file. I was encountering the same problem like you and this could solve the problem:

   ```
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>shade-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>shade</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <transformers>
                           <transformer
                                   implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                               <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                           </transformer>
                           <transformer
                                   implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                               <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                           </transformer>
                           <transformer
                                   implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                               <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                           </transformer>
                           <transformer
                                   implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                           <transformer
                                   implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                               <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                           </transformer>
                       </transformers>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.2.4</version>
           <configuration>
               <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
               <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
               <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   ```

Hope that it helps. Cheers!